# Unable to resolve the full path of the configuration file, /opt/mule/conf/wrapper.conf: No such file or directory

Tags: docker, mulesoft

Trying to deploy the mule application in Kubernetes. Getting the below issue

[image]

Below is my docker file:

```
FROM java:openjdk-8-jdk
RUN mkdir mule
#Adding Mule folder as a working directory inside a docker container
CMD echo "--- Adding MuleCE runtime in Docker Container ---"
RUN wget https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/mule/distributions/mule-standalone/4.3.0-20210119/mule-standalone-4.3.0-20210119.tar.gz && \
WORKDIR /mule
#Extract and install the Mule runtime in the container
CMD echo "--- Unzipping the added zip ---"
RUN  tar xvzf mule-standalone-${MULE_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
     rm mule-standalone-${MULE_VERSION}.tar.gz
# Define volume mount points
VOLUME      ["/mule/mule-standalone-4.3.0-20210119/logs", "/mule/mule-standalone-4.3.0-20210119/apps", "/mule/mule-standalone-4.3.0-20210119/domains"]
CMD echo "--- Deploying mule application in runtime ---"
COPY  mule-application.jar /mule/mule-standalone-4.3.0-20210119/apps/
RUN ls -ltr mule-standalone-4.3.0-20210119/apps/
# Expose the necessary port ranges as required by the Mule Apps

EXPOSE      6018

CMD echo "--- Starting Mule runtime ---"
CMD         ["/mule/mule-standalone-4.3.0-20210119/bin/mule"]
```

We are also given complete permissions for /opt/mule/conf path. So Could anyone suggest resolving this issue?

Comment: What's the issue?  How are you deploying this Docker image (what is the `docker run` command) and what result are you getting?  You included a PNG file in the question; can you include the source code that produces that?

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze, We used ```kubectl run demo --image=<image-name> --port=6018
``` command. In the same snapshot, we can see the logs generated by the pod.